# C# Binding with static resource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to set background color of my controls, depending on a punch of ruler. So, I am trying to use converters to do that.

In my XAML:

```
<TextBox Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}, ConverterParameter='UserName'}">
```

In my converter I find for a rule for "UserName". But I use the entire binding object for that:

```
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {

            var person = (value as PersonBase).Person;
            if (person.state == editing)
                return GetRulesFor(parameter);
            else
                return Brushes.Silver;
```

It works in the first time screen is showing, but I need to update these properties when user edit form, cancel, etc.

How can I set my binding for this to happen ?

Comment: Bind to the property in your view model and update it as necessary. You have no converter in this case. Note that the property must notify about changes (see INotifyPropertyCanged).

Comment: @paulo it does not know that `Person.state` has changed because it's bound to `PersonBase`. It won't trigger until bound value will change

Comment: Can I bound to a value, but has access to Person class in the converter?

Comment: You can use [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new property in the viewmodel and call it State, and return the person.state. When you change the state of the person object is changed just call OnPropertyChanged("State").

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   // ... your code here
   public StateObjectType State
   {
       get {return person.state;}
   }

   // when you modify the person state just call OnPropertyChanged("State")
}
```

In your view bind the textbox

```
<TextBox Background="{Binding State,Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}, ConverterParameter='UserName'}">
```

This will make your code works.